# CORS, Amazon S3, and Rails - Fails on IE 10 and Safari

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, internet-explorer-10

IE 10 supports CORS.
Amazon S3 supports CORS.

We have direct-from-site-to-S3 uploading working in all browsers but IE 10 (not bothering with IE 9-). It works like this:

1. User picks a file (drag and drop or pick from file input)
2. (POST) We have to "sign" the request before it goes to S3 (`$.post('/static/sign_asset', { ... }`) which has a callback that fires perfectly all day long.
3. (POST) We then make the XHR to S3 with the file data and the data from the signing and such.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// etc
var fd = new FormData();
// etc
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.send(fd);
```

The file uploads, everything works perfectly in all browsers except...

### Problems start in IE 10:

4. **Origin null not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.** and **XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.** No other browsers are showing this after we have set `response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"` in the controller that sends the response. Even when we had this wrong, Chrome would show this error, but the request would still go through.
5. The file actually does get uploaded to S3, despite this error. Amazon S3 does it's [303 redirect thing](http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html#Dealing_with_Success) - which is our verification that the file was successfully uploaded.
6. (GET) This is a redirect on a CORS Ajax request, so the "redirect" doesn't refresh the page it just comes back and hits our servers. IE 10 makes this request with a
   Content-Type of `multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7dd2ce2201da`

**This is what causes Rails to bug out.**

```
Started GET "/static/signed/asset/tsabat/83ee6840-7158-0130-c19b-28cfe912f6ff?bucket=s.cdpn.io&key=5%2Fauthor-tim_2.jpg&etag=%2260fb3876d516553ff6f3a018066b3250%22" for 127.0.0.1 at
 2013-03-17 10:46:36 -0700

EOFError - bad content body:
  (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:74:in `block in Rack::Multipart::Parser#fast_forward_to_first_boundary'  (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:72:in `Rack::Multipart::Parser#fast_forward_to_first_boundary'
  (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:72:in `Rack::Multipart::Parser#parse'
  (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/multipart/parser.rb:15:in `Rack::Multipart.parse_multipart'
  (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/multipart.rb:25:in `ActionDispatch::Request#parse_multipart'
  (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/request.rb:336:in `ActionDispatch::Request#POST'
  (gem) rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/request.rb:201:in `ActionDispatch::Request#POST'
```

### Safari fails too (6.0.2)

Safari returns a 200 status code and Rails doesn't freak out about the redirect, but the xhr.status is wrong. xhr.readyState == 4, but xhr.status == 0. We were looking for 200 to make sure it worked OK. That is easy enough to fix, but still...

Chrome does fine <sup><sub>(<dead image link removed>)</sub></sup> - Doesn't appear to even set Content-Type

Firefox does fine <sub><sup>(<dead image link removed>)</sup></sub> - Content-Type `application/json; charset=utf-8`

---

There are [example pages](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/CORSUpload/Default.html) that show how well IE 10 handles CORS, but they don't deal with this redirect issue.

Comment: I'm going to give you a +1 just in case you're really Chris Coyier. (Also the question is well-written so it deserves the +1 anyway, but your CSS-tricks site... is my stylecheatsheet.)

Comment: Have you tried examining the incoming/outgoing traffic with [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)? I would be curious what the headers look like for IE, compared to Chrome.

Comment: Headers for IE == http://cl.ly/Ndii

Comment: Headers for Chrome == http://cl.ly/NdOD

Comment: @ChrisCoyier I reached out through twitter. Would love to troubleshoot on a live example if at all possible. As you pointed out, there are many great examples of IE10 working very well with CORS, so I'm curious what could be causing these issues. Let me know if that type of access could be arranged.

Comment: @CamiloMartin He really is https://twitter.com/chriscoyier/status/313389221660479490

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CodePen team member here.  We figured this out...

We wanted to depend on the 303 redirect built into S3's POST functionality, but it proved to be problematic, as shown above. Instead we  simply stopped using the [S3 Form Field](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTForms.html#HTTPPOSTFormFields) `success_action_redirect` and switched to `success_action_status`.

For posterity, don't depend on the S3's 303 redirect to work consistently across browsers for xhr requests.  If you do, you'll spend your time fighting invalid headers, null origins, and dragons.

Comment: I'd always used success_action_redirect, from tutorials, never relying on _status, but didn't have the entire knowledge to answer. Glad I was right (or at least the tutorial I was following was!)!